# Databinding to a Hidden Aspxcombobox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, combobox, devexpress

I have an aspxGridView control to list some records. I am using a combobox to fill some data, which is different from aspxgridview's .

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_CellEditorInitialize(object sender, ASPxGridViewEditorEventArgs e)
{         
        if (e.Column.FieldName == "LnkHotelID")
        {
            ASPxComboBox cmb = e.Editor as ASPxComboBox;
            cmb.DataSource = DsHtel;
            cmb.ValueField = "HotelID";
            cmb.ValueType = typeof(Int32);
            cmb.TextField = "HotelName";
            cmb.DataBindItems();
        }            
}
```

I don't want to see "LnkHotelID" so I want it hidden. But when I hide this column, I can't use the function above. Also I want to see "HotelName" column but not to update it.

So I have two questions:

1) How can I access aspxcombobox at runtime?
2) How can I show my HotelName but not edit them?

Comment: please clarify your question. your question doesnt make sense

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Answer (score 0):

Set the **ASPxComboBox.ClientEnabled** property to False:

```
ASPxComboBox cmb = e.Editor as ASPxComboBox;
cmb.ClientEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score -1):

When you hide column with visible=false it will not render that in HTML so you can't use above function. So instead of visible false use style property with display: none

```
<style>
   .hiddencolumn {display:none;}
</style>

<asp:GridView ID="GridViewHotel" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
   <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LnkHotelID" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden"
        HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencolumn" />

</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Now you can use your code.